# Javascript Replacing All Instances of New Line Character ASCII (13) with "\r\n"?

Tags: javascript, newline, str-replace

How can I replace all instances of a newline character ASCII code (13) in a string with "\r\n"?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ASCII 13 (decimal) is carriage return, not newline.  Do you want to replace newlines, or replace decimal 13?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp All you need, hope it helps

Comment: (carriage return = '\r', newline = '\n')

Comment: *Please do not use W3Schools as a reference*, please see **[W3Fools](http://w3fools.com)** for a long list of reasons why. The [Mozilla Developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/) is one of [several](http://w3fools.com/#what-should-be-done) far superior HTML/CSS/Javascript references.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this to do it...

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(13), 'g'), '\r\n');
```

Naturally, if you don't need to pass a variable to get the char code (or if it's not clearer), use the character in a regex literal, e.g. `/\r/g`.

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(13) == '\r'` is always true, but nice use of showing `fromCharCode`.

Comment: @pst I should have taken the time to look it up :)

Comment: Needed to generate the character for my application. '\r' was not working, but it was for an Application API so maybe just a quirk.

Comment: thanks. working :) /*reg_address2  is textarea value with line feeds. try the below code. You will get an idea where does these line feed goes. */ var i =0;
                    for (i=0;i<reg_address2.length;i++){
                    console.log(reg_address2[i]+': '+reg_address2.charCodeAt(i));
                    }

Comment: How would I change this to to `chr(13) || chr(10)` as in `CRLF` to `\n`?

Answer (score 5):

ASCII code 13 is not a newline character, it is a carriage return which in many programming languages (including JavaScript) can be represented in strings with `\r`.

Here is how you can replace all occurences of `\r` in a string with `\r\n`:

```
str = str.replace(/\r/g, "\r\n");
```

Comment: '\n' is not ASCII(13)... not sure which part of the question to believe ;-)

Comment: Nope -- That will only replace the first occurrence!

Comment: @pst - Just noticed that myself, edited the answer so it should clarify a bit.

Comment: @InfinitiesLoop - Thanks, my JavaScript is a bit rusty, edited so it will now replace all.